# Prevent INSERT INTO ... SELECT statement from creating its own fresh snapshot

Tags: mysql, innodb, transaction-isolation

Is it possible for MySQL/MariaDb InnoDb engine to do `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement and use snapshot created by current `REPEATABLE READ` transaction?

Example (all statements run within one session except one mentioned below):

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
START TRANSACTION; -- snapshot 1 for this transaction is created
SELECT * FROM t1; -- result is 1 row, snapshot 1 is used
-- another transaction (different session) inserts and commits new row into t1 table
SELECT * FROM t1; -- result is still 1 row, because its REPEATABLE READ, still using snapshot 1
INSERT INTO t2 SELECT * FROM t1; -- this SELECT creates new snapshot 2
SELECT * FROM t2; -- result are 2 rows
SELECT * FROM t1; -- result is still 1 row, using snapshot 1
```

Is it possible to make this line:

```
INSERT INTO t2 SELECT * FROM t1; -- this SELECT creates new snapshot 2
```

... to use snapshot 1? And why is MySQL acting like this. Isn't it against Isolation principle?

This behaviour is documented here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html

> The type of read varies for selects in clauses like INSERT INTO ... SELECT, UPDATE ... (SELECT), and CREATE TABLE ... SELECT that do not specify FOR UPDATE or FOR SHARE:
>
> By default, InnoDB uses stronger locks and the SELECT part acts like READ COMMITTED, where each consistent read, even within the same transaction, **sets and reads its own fresh snapshot**.

Here are some possible structures of tables used above:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=InnoDB; 
CREATE TABLE t2 (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The only important is the InnoDB engine.

Comment: I don't think you can workaround this without using the mentioned hint. But you can create your own "snapshot" in the beginning by selecting the data into a temp table. After that you work with the temp table

Comment: i assume these statements are run within one session? As that is not really 100% clear from the question.. if not it should help to separted the SQL statements.. Can you also provide us with a table structure of those tables? `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` for every table involved in the question/query..

Comment: @PeterHe Yes, temp table is an option. But if you want to work with more tables and still have consisten reads across all these tables, then you have a problem.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, it's within one session. I have added that into original question. The table structure really does not matter in this case, it can be just one row table, e.g.:
CREATE TABLE t1 (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE t2 (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=InnoDB;